# how can i colour whole row in DBGrid with rowselect turned off?

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

RowSelect breaks the functionality of OnCellClick, so I need to turn RowSelect off.
So then how can I simulate to look of row select by highlighting the all the cell of the current row?

Comment: Doesn't this question essentially ask how to fix RowSelect? Is this RowSelect-OnCellClick incompatibility bug documented somewhere?

Comment: You're absolutly right, sorry. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TDBGrid.OnDrawColumnCell` event, and set the `State` to indicate the row is selected.

```
procedure TfrmPrimaryCare.dbGrdPCClaimsDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  NewState: TGridDrawState;
  RowSelected: Boolean;
begin
  NewState := State;
  RowSelected := (Sender as TDBGrid).SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected;
  if (RowSelected) then
    NewState := NewState + [gdSelected];
  TDBGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, NewState);
end;
```

Comment: But what is the ThisRowIsSelected ?

Comment: Just to clarify, I know how to colour cells, but I don't know how I detect if the row is the currently selected row.

Comment: Your question specifically asks "how can I simulate to look of row select by highlighting the all the cell of the current row?", which is the question I answered. If you have a different question about how to keep track of selected rows with `dgRowSelect = False`, ask a new question. :-)

Comment: I have an answer to your other question (about detecting if the current row is selected), whenever you get around to posting it as a new question.

Comment: Rephrased question here; [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828991/how-to-keep-track-of-selected-rows-with-dgrowselect-false) Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Answered new question, as promised.

Comment: @KenWhite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170720/dbgrid-custom-draw-gdrowselected-not-working .......

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me ( `dgRowSelect=False` and `dgMultiSelect=False` ): 
Declare hack types for `DBGrid` and `GridDataLink` to access protected methods
and two variables

```
type
  THackGrid = class(TDBGrid);
  THackDataLink = class(TGridDataLink);
var
  HackGrid: THackGrid;
  HackDataLink: THackDataLink;
```

In `OnFormCreate` assign the variables to have them available at drawing time:

```
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HackGrid := THackGrid(MainGrid);
  HackDataLink := THackDataLink(HackGrid.DataLink);
end;
```

and test selected row using `TGridDataLink.GetActiveRecord`:

```
procedure TMyForm.MainGridDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn;
  State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if Not (gdSelected in State) and (HackGrid.Row = HackDataLink.GetActiveRecord + 1) then
    MainGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clInfoBk;

  MainGrid.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```