# Detect which cell was clicked in TDBGrid when dgRowSelect is set to True?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tdbgrid

In Delphi 2010 is there any way to detect which cell was clicked when `dgRowSelect` is set to True ?

Normally I would use the `OnCellClick(Column: TColumn)` event handler, but this does not work as expected. With `dgRowSelect = False` this procedure gets passed the column that was clicked, but  with `dgRowSelect = True` this procedure is passed the first column, regardless of which column was clicked.

I can't work out where the code is that calls the `OnCellClick` passing in the `TColumn` parameter, if I could find that I might be able to work out how to fix this odd behaviour.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the mouse coordinates to get the column. After calling `TDBGrid.MouseCoord`, the returned `TGridCoord.X` contains the column number, and the `Y` contains the row (which, of course, you already have):

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
  Coord: TGridCoord;
  ClickCol: Integer;
begin
  Pt := DBGrid1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  Coord := DBGrid1.MouseCoord(Pt.X, Pt.Y);
  ClickCol := Coord.X;
  ShowMessage('You clicked column ' + IntToStr(ClickCol));
end;
```

More info on `TGridCoord` in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Grids.TGridCoord).

Tested using the same app used for my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13829114/62576).

Comment: Perfect answer. Gives me exactly what i need. If it helps anyone else i used this to give me the name of the database field;     DBGrid1.Columns[ClickCol - 1].Field.FieldName

Comment: +1 This answer helped me too, but is it me or there is something wrong with the naming of the properties? Normally mouse coordinates are understood as screen relative position.

Comment: The ScreenToClient might do the conversion, am I right?

Comment: @LaureanoBonilla: The `ScreenToClient` converts to grid-specific coordinates, which are passed to `MouseCoord` to convert to row/column location.