# DBGrid custom draw gdRowSelected not working

Tags: delphi, drawing, delphi-xe2, tdbgrid

I'm custom drawing in a DBGrid by monitoring `OnDrawColumnCell` to color the column. When I read the event handler's `State`, I successfully capture `gdSelected` and color the font in the selected cell. But when I monitor [`gdRowSelected`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Grids.TGridDrawState), it's never there, and thus I can't tell when a row is selected.

Why doesn't `gdRowSelected` ever apply? Is this a bug, or intentional functionality?

Here's how I currently draw. When a row is selected, it should show the text in that row in the color red.

```
procedure TForm1.gItemsDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Rec: TRect;
  function C: TCanvas;
  begin
    Result:= gItems.Canvas;
  end;
begin
  //Evaluating gdSelected works fine, but not gdRowSelected
  if gdRowSelected in State then begin
    C.Font.Color:= clRed;
  end else begin
    C.Font.Color:= clWhite;
  end;
  C.Brush.Style:= bsSolid;
  C.Brush.Color:= clBlack;
  C.Pen.Style:= psClear;
  C.FillRect(Rect);
  C.Brush.Style:= bsClear;
  C.Pen.Style:= psSolid;
  Rec:= R;
  DrawText(C.Handle, PChar(Column.Field.AsString), Length(Column.Field.AsString),
    Rec, 0);
end;
```

The documentation states

> gdRowSelected - The row is selected.

but it's never in the State.

---

**EDIT**

I tried enabling the option `dgRowSelect` and it does make a change, but it's still only monitoring the `gdSelected` enum and never `gdRowSelected`. With `dgRowSelect` enabled, `gdSelected` is in the state for each cell in the entire row. But still `gdRowSelected` is never in the state.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824573/how-can-i-colour-whole-row-in-dbgrid-with-rowselect-turned-off?rq=1

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13829114/62576) help? Funny: I posted this link as your comment hit my inbox. :-)

Comment: Yes, it helps, and I saw it prior to asking my question, but it still doesn't explain why `gdRowSelected` doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: It does, actually. You have to check `TDBGrid.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected` instead, as that answer shows. `gdSelected` indicates that the *cell* should be considered selected, and `CurrentRowSelected` indicates that the entire *row* is selected (when `dgRowSelect` is included in `Options`).

Comment: @KenWhite Understood, and that does work, but why would `gdRowSelected` be in the `State` for no reason? Isn't that what it's meant for?

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work. :-) I just know that the solution in that post does, and so it's an acceptable workaround to me.

Comment: @Jerry - Regarding your edited edit, not that it invalidates the question, but then you don't really need 'gdRowSelected', do you?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I'm trying to figure out why it never does anything