# hyperlink field in DBGRID

Tags: delphi, dbgrid, tdbgrid

I'm doing a small internal software to search branch lines in my company. In addition to the branch lines I also put an e-mail field in the database as shown below:

[image]

My intention is to click on the registered e-mail and the software via the `ShellExecute` open a window to send the e-mail. I'm using the option `dgRowSelect` as `TRUE` and because of that the `OnCellClick` event does not correctly identify which cell was clicked.

In my searches have not found any way to do this. Then I thought of using a `TLabel` within the field. I can use the `onclick` event in the `TLabel` and also change the cursor icon.

If `TLabel` is a good solution, how can I add a TLabel in DBGrid?

Or what would be another good solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that purpose of dgRowSelect=true is for highlighting whole selected row.
TLabel is not the way I would go - I would set dgRowSelect=false and paint selected row in OnDrawColumnCell or create my own fixed dbgrid. 
There was a similar question:
[how can i colour whole row in DBGrid with rowselect turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824573/how-can-i-colour-whole-row-in-dbgrid-with-rowselect-turned-off)

Anyway if you want to use dgRowSelect=true and get valid info about clicked cell, here it is:

```
type THackDBGrid=class(TDBGrid);


procedure TForm1.dbgrd1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
var p:TPoint;
    col:TGridCoord;
    i: Integer;
    grid:THackDBGrid;

begin
    p := Mouse.CursorPos;
    grid := THackDBGrid(Column.Grid);
    p := grid.ScreenToClient(p);
    col := grid.MouseCoord(p.X,p.Y);
    i := grid.RawToDataColumn(col.X);
    Label1.Caption := 'Column index: ' +  IntToStr(i);
end;
```

Comment: You could clean your code up a lot by declaring `var Grid: THackDBGrid`, and then as the first line of the procedure assigning it with `Grid := THackDBGrid(DBGrid1);`. All of the remaining typecasts would then be unnecessary, as you could simply refer to `Grid.ScreenToClient`, `Grid.MouseCoord`, etc.

Comment: Even better if change `DBGrid1` for `Column.Grid`